# How to achieve an absolute percentage scale in ggplot with scales::label_percent?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got the following y-axis scale in ggplot

```
library(scales)

demo_continuous(c(-0.5, 0, 1))
```

I would like to have an absolute percentage scale. I figured out how to do an absolut scale using

```
demo_continuous(c(-0.5, 0, 1), labels = base::abs)
```

And I know how to do a percentage scale using

```
demo_continuous(c(-0.5, 0, 1), labels = scales::label_percent(accuracy = 0.1))
```

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58849029/how-to-achieve-an-absolute-percentage-scale-in-ggplot), I also figured out how to do an absolute percentage scale using

```
demo_continuous(c(-0.5, 0, 1), labels = function(x) scales::percent(base::abs(x)))
```

However, `scales::percent` is superseded by `scales::label_percent` and I did not figure out how to do the same thing using `scales::label_percent` instead of `scales::percent`.

**Question:** How to replicate `function(x) scales::percent(base::abs(x))` using `scales::label_percent`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `label_percent()` function creates a function itself that is then called on the numbers.

```r
library(scales)
label_percent()
#> function (x) 
#> {
#>     number(x, accuracy = accuracy, scale = scale, prefix = prefix, 
#>         suffix = suffix, big.mark = big.mark, decimal.mark = decimal.mark, 
#>         style_positive = style_positive, style_negative = style_negative, 
#>         scale_cut = scale_cut, trim = trim, ...)
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x7f86274ba7e0>
#> <environment: 0x7f86274b99a8>
```

So, you can just call that function in your labeling function as below:

```r
demo_continuous(c(-0.5, 0, 1), labels = function(x)label_percent()(abs(x)))
#> scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) label_percent()(abs(x)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>